# Monitoring users usage of a saas application

Tags: saas, web-analytics

I am trying to find a way to learn more on users behaviour in a SaaS web application, in order to improve the UI experience, and to know which features are most used, in what way, etc

The application is for organizations (and is hosted outside the organization's network), so we need the data in-house (not in some third-party service).

Are there products that I can install on my server for this purpose, or do I need to develop my own custom solution?

I am developing on Asp.Net MVC 4.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any out of the box solution to understand the application usage, Customer behavior, pattern etc, but from my experience of being an developer of SaaS Application framework provider and developer you have to consider the below points for an effective analysis, they are

1. Log each individual feature & method access by the users
2. Log each independent urls access along with the time, browser and other additional details possible.

With this you will be able to identify the analytics on how well the features and modules of your applications are utilized, what are the highly utilized features, customers behavior etc. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Piwik and Snowplow, although I am not sure if both them allow custom event tracking.

http://demo.piwik.org is an open source web analytics platform that provides insights into your website’s visitors, your marketing campaigns etc. Its similar to Google Analytics, and can be hosted on your own server.

http://snowplowanalytics.com/ is a new open source project, and allows you to run analytics on your customer-level and event-level data.